# How to get structured logs in Firebase CLI?

Tags: javascript, firebase, console, google-cloud-functions, command-line-interface

I have a node script that prints logs generated by all my firebase cloud functions.

```js
const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const cmd = "firebase functions:log";
let options = {
    encoding: 'utf8'
}
let output = execSync(cmd, options)

console.log(output)
```

Outputs look something like this:

```
2021-01-06T09:06:05.541212726Z D saveGarment: Function execution took 736 ms, finished with status code: 204
2021-01-06T09:06:10.844901031Z D saveGarment: Function execution started
2021-01-06T09:06:16.153Z ? saveGarment: CORE
2021-01-06T09:06:18.134508823Z D saveGarment: Function execution took 7470 ms, finished with status code: 200
2021-01-06T09:06:19.546Z ? saveGarment: { message: 'fail' }
```

The output of the script is in the form of a string. Is there any way to receive all the logs in a JSON /any other structured format or do we need to use the string parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#custom-logs), theres a lot of ways you can send the data to the logs.

Judging by your comments, I would recommend you to check the example [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/blob/master/samples/logs.js#L43) as it holds something like what you seem to be trying to send to the logs.